# VS2013: Git and TFS confusion

Tags: git, version-control, visual-studio-2013, tfs-workitem

I am a bit puzzled how things work with version control and work items, so I will explain my goal, what I did and where I got stuck.

I would like to track work items and source code changes while developing .NET application. I have tested TFS source control and work items and the way I see it works, TFS stores data on the SqlServer, and is adding / modifying files under the solution folder. I discovered that with VS2013 there is also Git source control, and I noticed that it creates a separate folder and does not add / modify files in each project folder, which I prefer.

So, this is what I did:

- cleaned solution from TFS version control, and deleted all team projects from TFS.
- added solution to Git source control, which created .git folder under solution, and showed local repository in Team explorer.
- did an initial commit. After completed, it showed message that it is not synced, and that I need to provide a remote repository so I can sync to it.

At this point version control works, I can see changes, compare source. However, there is no WorkItems entry in Team explorer. It seems that it is part of TFS, and Git does not have similar feature.

Questions:

- do I need to create a Team project under TFS in order to have WorkItems?
- do I really need a remote repository? I am a single developer, so there is actually no team and nothing to share.
- when I open a solution, how can I have WorkItems and Changes for this solution, the same as I had it when I used TFS source control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Do I need to create a Team project under TFS in order to have WorkItems?*

Yes, you need a team project that has a Git Repository for source control. Git uses what we call "mentions" in the comment box. When you enter a comment that includes `#12345`, TFS will detect this and link the commit in Git to the workitem with id 12345.

*Do I really need a remote repository? I am a single developer, so there is actually no team and nothing to share.*

If you want TFS to have a secure copy of your sources, then yes. You need a local repository to which you do your initial commits and then when you're satisfied, you push these changes to TFS (which will act as you remote repository). It is only then when work items will be associated.

*When I open a solution, how can I have WorkItems and Changes for this solution, the same as I had it when I used TFS source control?*

Push the changes to the remote (TFS Server).